# Tool for checking for in-memory code modifications of loaded DLLs

Tags: tools, windows, dll

A common anti-debugging practice is to overwrite functions such as DbgUiRemoteBreakin within ntdll.dll.

Since in-memory representation of common libraries is always the same on each platform, it should be possible for an external tool to connect to a process and compare in-memory library code with a reference in order to find any manipulations done by the process itself.

Does anybody know such a tool for Windows?

Comment: Try to look into this thread, I thinks it could at least partially answer your question [Tool for checking if there is any patch in the loaded module](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2276/tool-for-checking-if-there-is-any-patch-in-the-loaded-module)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[WinDbg can do this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff562217%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for Microsoft DLLs and executables (and generally for any code that can be obtained from the symbol server). Just attach the debugger to the process and do `!chkimg <module>`. It will download a clean copy of the module from the symbol server and compare it, reporting on differences.

[This article](http://community.websense.com/blogs/securitylabs/archive/2010/04/29/analyzing-malwares-using-microsoft-tools.aspx) has an example of the output you can expect to see when something has modified a binary.

Comment: The described manipulation is usually used for terminating the process when an debugger is attached. Therefore only the variant by analyzing a process memory dump would be possible.

Answer (score 3):

You can attach to the process `non invasive` and use !`chkimg !chkallimg !chksym` commands.

Look for `non invasive check box` in the attach to process dialog in `windbg` or use `.attach -v "pid"`

Attaching in a non invasive way minimizes debugger interference and in most cases will not trigger the anti-debugging routines.

Comment: I was looking at your answers and saw that some of them were missing punctuation. I made some edits but in the future, please try to incorporate these into your answers as it makes them much more easier to read. Thanks!